# Can I deploy Azure AD B2C service using ARM Template or by Powershell?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-rm-template

How to deploy Azure AD B2C service using ARMTemplate or either by using Powershell commandlets?

Any help, highly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Hi, currently, it is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible. Please refer to this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/18960694-deploy-and-manage-active-directory-b2c-using-arm-t).